# Search Dialogue not activated when onSearchRequested is called (Android)

Tags: java, android

Beginner working on an android app and I'm trying to start a searchable activity when the onSearchRequested method is called after a button push in the main activity. Currently, when the button is pressed, nothing happens.

Here's MainActivity.Java:

```
package com.example.activity2;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                onSearchRequested();
            }
        });

        }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
  //  public void sendMessage(View view)
   // {    

  //  }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here's the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.activity2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission
         android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" />
                <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value="com.example.activity2.SearchActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.authorwjf.youtubeapi.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_activity2" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SearchActivity" >
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.activity2.SEARCHACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"  />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".OtherActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_other" >

            <!-- enable the search dialog to send searches to SearchableActivity -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".SearchActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchListView"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_list_view" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchYoutube"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_youtube" >
        </activity>
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

SearchActivity.Java

```
package com.example.activity2;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchResult;

public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lst;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_activity);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
          ArrayList<SearchResult> results = new ArrayList<SearchResult>();
          Iterator<SearchResult> it = results.iterator();
          SearchYoutube.prettyPrint(it, query);
          lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
          ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, SearchYoutube.ytstuff);
          lst.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any Definition of onSearchRequested(); ? please post it.

Comment: Here's the description:                                       boolean android.app.Activity.onSearchRequested()


This hook is called when the user signals the desire to start a search. 

You can use this function as a simple way to launch the search UI, in response to a menu item, search button, or other widgets within your activity. Unless overidden, calling this function is the same as calling startSearch(null, false, null, false), which launches search for the current activity as specified in its manifest, see SearchManager.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say I'm programming for Android

Comment: @yoyoyo : In your AndroidManifest for your .MainActivity you have the `meta-data` element inside the `<intent-filter>` element. It should be in the main part of the `<Activity` element.

Comment: @Squonk Man, I thought you'd solved it! But I'm still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement your search activity.

```
public class SearchableActivity extends ListActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
          Log.d("SEARCH", "HERE");
          handleIntent(getIntent()); 
       } 

       public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) { 
          setIntent(intent); 
          handleIntent(intent); 
       } 

       public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) { 
          // call the appropriate detail activity
       } 

       private void handleIntent(Intent intent) { 
          if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) { 
             String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY); 
             doSearch(query); 
          } 
       }    

       private void doSearch(String queryStr) { 
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), queryStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } 
}
```

And specify the meta-data in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
    android:value=".SearchableActivity" />

<activity
    android:name=".SearchableActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

Comment: I've already done that. I posted my manifest file in the OP. I'll edit with my SearchActivity.

Comment: In your question, <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" /> is associated with MainActivity. Change it with SearchActivity.

Comment: Do I have to remove everything else from the intent filter as well? I tried what you suggested and still no search dialogue.

Comment: First you need to clean your AndroidManifest, your meta-data is in every activity expect for SearchActivity which needs it. Please refer the answer I provided and just use metadata and SEARCH action in SearchActivity. For SEARCH action and meta-data from other activities

Comment: Removed everything but <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" /> from the intent filter. Still have the same issue. Here's my current manifest:

Answer (score 3):

In your `searchable.xml` file in the `xml` folder, the label cannot be hardcoded. It should be like `@string/name` or search dialogue wont show.

Comment: Worked for me!! Thanks!