# How to make linear layout clicked to show search widget?

Tags: android

I am creating a Linear Layout and I want make it clickable. When I press the layout, search widget should appear. I am using `android:clickable="true"`. When I press on the layout, it does not work. I have added `android:onClick="btword"` to the layout and following code:

```
public void btword(View v) {
    onSearchRequested();
}
```

to my java file but it has no effect.
Could anyone share if there is a way to make it clickable?

xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="200dp"   
      android:background="@drawable/second_bg" 
      android:id="@+id/l" 
      android:clickable="true" 
      android:onClick="btword" 
      android:orientation="vertical" > 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is your linear layout empty ??

Comment: Yes it is empty. but I want when I click it the search widget appear.

Comment: ok , and mostly the height is set to be `wrap_content` that's mean while the linear layout is empty that the height is zero. so try to fix the height to `50dp` for example and try to click on it.

Comment: I try that but doesn't work !!!

Comment: add your xml code please .

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/second_bg"
    android:id="@+id/l"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="btword"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>`

Comment: I tried it and it works. The problem is in your function `onSearchRequested();` Debug and you'll see that `btword` function is called

Comment: what I do to solve that the search widget appear only when I call this function .

Comment: are the search widget appear when you click the layout??

Comment: The problem as I told you is in `onSearchRequested()` not in the click listener see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25212487/1535314) , it may help you.

Comment: I add button when clicked the search widget appear but I do it for the layout not work

Answer (score 0):

In your xml add

```
android:clickable="true"
```

for the desired `LinearLayout`

Then just like a button, implement OnClickListener for that `LinearLayout`

```
LinearLayout mLinLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linLayoutId);

mLinLayout.setOnclickListener(this);
```

Comment: Thanks I do that but there is no any effect !! :(

Comment: Did you implemented OnClickListener and override the onClick method?
mLinLayout.setOnclickListener(new View.OnclickListener){
.
.

}